# How to use ZTE MU350 USB modem?

Tags: 10.10, configuration, usb-modem, usb-modeswitch

Hello everyone i'm a newbie loving the ubuntu experience. I have a problem connecting my usb modem specified in the title on a CDMA network in Ghana(expresso), I did some searching and found the usb_modeswitch.

I have downloaded the latest tar.bz2 for the program and the data package. My question do i just need to compile and install this software and my modem will out of the box like in Win7.

NB: Even in windows the autorun works only the first time the modem is plugged in, afterwards if modem is plugged in, Win7 recognises it but i have launch the GUI to be able to use the modem unlike other modems in which the GUI pops up everytime the modem is plugged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this page: [How do I use Expresso’s Cliq Modem in ubuntu?](http://japopo.tumblr.com/post/5022093865/how-do-i-use-expressos-cliq-modem-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Please include [more than just a link](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/257/how-does-ask-ubuntu-work/542#542)

Answer (score 1):

try the steps in this blog [connecting usb modem in ubuntu](http://abhishekdelta.wordpress.com/2010/05/18/connecting-mts-mblaze-usb-modem-in-ubuntu/) ( change the settings according to your service provider ) ...meanwhile my ZTE modem works out of the box in 10.10 and 11.04. I just have to wait 5-7 mins and enable mobile broadband and the choose a new connection appears in network manager!  [and this is how I connect in 10.10 and 11.04](http://randomshandom.wordpress.com/2010/12/20/how-to-connect-mts-mblaze-device-in-ubuntu-10-10/)